# Multiplication Table with Random - C#

Tags: c#, random, multiplication

Im going to explain what Im trying to do as concrete as possible.
Currently im working on a little test project with Windows Forms (c#) and am trying to create a program that can help children train the "multiplication tabel" between 1-10.

I have occured a problem which I dont know how to solve regarding how I'd make the randoms work in this way.

So, what I want to do is call a method/class like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Just a clickevent from a formsbutton.
{
    richtextbox1.Text = methodRandomValue.toString();
    richtextbox2.Text = methodRandomValue.toString();

}

public int methodRandomValue()
{
    int temporaryvalue = 0: //Will get the value from the randomgenerator.

    Random randomgenerator = new Random();
    ////Im stuck here.
    ////

    return temporaryvalue;
}
```

So, this is supposed to return two values that will be shown to the user via two richtextboxes. Now, I dont know how I will make this happen as I do not want a math problem to return twice. I.ex. if 4 * 5 have already been present, I dont want this to return again, same with 5 * 4.

I must somehow tell the Random function that it should not randomize a situation that have been seen before - this is what I need help with. This should result in 54 unique situations: (1 * 1, 1 * 2, 1 * 3... 1 * 10) (2 * 2, 2 * 3...2 * 10) (3 * 3...) etc,

Example: So the order could be 5 * 4 then 3 * 8 then 2 * 7, but they will never return if once present, so the next numbers would not be 4 * 5 or 5 * 4 as it have already occured in this example.

Sorry if I've written confusing and do tell me if I need to explain better. English is not my better subject.

Edit:

[image]

Here's a picture of what It would look like in debug mode. So first I want the method to generate one random number between 1-10 for the first textbox, then I want the same thing for the secound textbox. But I dont want, say if the first situation is 1*1 like in the picture, I dont want this to be able to occur again. So, in someway the random would skip 1*1 as it've already happend.

Comment: your retourning the same random for both textboxes,and by what you explained it will be for example 5 * 5 or 7 * 7,unless you explained it wrong....shouldnt the second textbox be the number 1 to 10?...and also very confusing why random to do multiplication table...

Comment: I want to make the training random so that people dont just learn the order but actually look at the numbers present. If I'd make it static the order would be the same all the time. I have an example of what Im trying to do here.. http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/math-trainer-multiply.html . The richtextbox1 would be the first number and richtextbox2 would be the secound.

Answer (score 0):

I will present you with an alternative.I warn you its a very simplistic one but i think it serves the purpose.You can just copy&paste to a new project and just place a button and a textbox in the upper right corner of the form(just because its where i put it for testing and the x and y coordinates of the drawstring will draw just bellow,you can change that offcourse) and then just insert a number in the textbox and click the button.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        bool canInvalidate = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            canInvalidate = true;
            Invalidate();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (canInvalidate)
            {
                float x = 20, y = 50;
                int chosen = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                foreach (var item in numbers)
                {
                    int result = chosen * item;
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(string.Format("{0} * {1} = {2}", chosen, item, result), Font, Brushes.Black, x, y);
                    y += 10;
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)|| e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

PS:you also have to wireup the keypress event in your project :)

Ofcourse you dont even need to have the hardcoded list.If so just place this in the foreach loop:

```
foreach (var item in Enumerable.Range(1,10))
```

As you see you can pick a number at will(your random factor) and see the results.

Comment: Im not really sure what your code does, and I did make a test project and copy/pasted the code into the project after creating a button and a textbox. However, when I debug the program, nothing happends at all. Besides that, I think you have misunderstood my question.

Comment: nothing happens because you have to wireup the eventhandlers for the button click,for the form paint and textbox keypress...after that just write a number in the textbox and click the button